# Javascript Product Search (working, but need to filter by search term)

Tags: javascript, html, search

I have a little product search code that I've been working on for a while. It works great, although a bit backwards.

The more keywords I type in, ideally, the less products will show up (because it narrows down the results). But as is stands, the more keywords I type in my search system, the MORE products are displayed, because it looks for any product with any of the keywords.
I want to change the script so that it ***only shows results if they include ALL the searched for keywords, not ANY of them...***

Sorry for the long-winded explanation.

**Here's the meat and potatoes (jsfiddle):**

http://jsfiddle.net/yk0Lhneg/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="edit_search" onkeyup="find_my_div();">
<input type="button" onClick="find_my_div();" value="Find">
<div id="product_0" class="name" style="display:none">Mac
    <br/>Apple
    <br/>
    <br/>
</div>
<div id="product_1" class="name" style="display:none">PC
    <br/>Windows
    <br/>
    <br/>
</div>
<div id="product_2" class="name" style="display:none">Hybrid
    <br/>Mac PC Apple Windows
    <br/>
    <br/>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function gid(a_id) {
    return document.getElementById(a_id);
}

function close_all() {

    for (i = 0; i < 999; i++) {
        var o = gid("product_" + i);
        if (o) {
            o.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

}


function find_my_div() {
    close_all();

    var o_edit = gid("edit_search");
    var str_needle = edit_search.value;
    str_needle = str_needle.toUpperCase();
    var searchStrings = str_needle.split(/\W/);

    for (var i = 0, len = searchStrings.length; i < len; i++) {
        var currentSearch = searchStrings[i].toUpperCase();
        if (currentSearch !== "") {
            nameDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("name");
            for (var j = 0, divsLen = nameDivs.length; j < divsLen; j++) {
                if (nameDivs[j].textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(currentSearch) !== -1) {
                    nameDivs[j].style.display = "block";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, when you search "mac pc" the only result that should be displayed is the hybrid, because it has both of those keywords. Not all 3 products.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed a little bit your code to adjust it better to my solution. I hope you don't mind. You loop first over the terms, and then through the list of products, I do it the other way around.

How this solution works:

- Traverse the list of products, for each product:

  - Create a counter and set it to 0.
  - Traverse the list of search terms, for each.

    - If the word is found in the product's name, add 1 to the counter.
  - If the counter has the same value as the list length, display the product (matched all words)

```js
function gid(a_id) {
    return document.getElementById(a_id);
}

function close_all() {
    
    for (i = 0; i < 999; i++) {
        var o = gid("product_" + i);
        if (o) {
            o.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    
}


function find_my_div() {
    close_all();
    
    var o_edit = gid("edit_search");
    var str_needle = edit_search.value;
    str_needle = str_needle.toUpperCase();
    var searchStrings = str_needle.split(/\W/);
    
    // I moved this loop outside
    var nameDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("name");
    for (var j = 0, divsLen = nameDivs.length; j < divsLen; j++) {

        // set a counter to zero
        var num = 0;

        // I moved this loop inside
        for (var i = 0, len = searchStrings.length; i < len; i++) {
            var currentSearch = searchStrings[i].toUpperCase();
            // only run the search if the text input is not empty (to avoid a blank)
            if (str_needle !== "") {
                // if the term is found, add 1 to the counter
                if (nameDivs[j].textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(currentSearch) !== -1) {
                    num++;
                }
                // display only if all the terms where found
                if (num == searchStrings.length) {
                    nameDivs[j].style.display = "block";
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="edit_search" onkeyup="find_my_div();">
<input type="button" onClick="find_my_div();" value="Find">
<div id="product_0" class="name" style="display:none">Mac
    <br/>Apple
    <br/>
    <br/>
</div>
<div id="product_1" class="name" style="display:none">PC
    <br/>Windows
    <br/>
    <br/>
</div>
<div id="product_2" class="name" style="display:none">Hybrid
    <br/>Mac PC Apple Windows
    <br/>
    <br/>
</div>
```

You can also see it on this version of your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yk0Lhneg/1/

Comment: thank you so much for your help! Your solution works perfectly, and Is exactly what I need. Great job thinking outside the box and reordering the operations! Very impressive!! :)